# What alternatives are there in OS projects for c# similar to Joomla/Mambo/Drupal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drupal, joomla

I'm beginning a project with a client to build a web application and I'm a little stuck on which solution to go with.

I've used Joomla for many clients in the past, but this client has specific requests that I KNOW I'm going to have to build myself.

The problem I'm facing is that I work full time under the .NET spectrum and while I am a novice developer in PHP, and I've been studying Joomla's plug in architecture for about a month now, I am a lot more comfortable building something in ASP.NET than I am in PHP.

**My question is, what OS projects are out there that have a similar community following as Joomla/Mambo/Drupal, along with a plug in architecture that is somewhat akin to Joomla as well?**

I don't really have the time to build out a full blown CMS system in ASP.NET, but if something already exists that can give me X% (25%, 50%, something) of what Joomla has that will at least get me on the right path.  Joomla just has too many extensions and too much of a community backing for me to pass it up if there's not something comparable in the ASP.NET realm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've use (and struggled with) [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/).

Comment: I've used DNN before, but it seemed fairly slow.  It does however, have an extension framework built into it that I watched some podcasts on.  I never developed anything for it though.  The biggest problem with DNN is that it just doesn't have enough "stuff" yet, compared to Joomla.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I'm also kind of wondering if there is something out there that's being started using the MVC framework.  +1 for DNN though.

Comment: DNN is not as slow as it used to be fortunately.

Comment: +1 for DNN. It has a learning curve, but definitely gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

N2 looks quite nice, I haven't been using it though: http://n2cms.com/

Answer (score 3):

in addition to N2, mentioned above (of which i am a big fan), there's an option (for really brave souls!) to run Drupal on top of .Net with Phalanger compiler -- it requires several patches to Phalanger and at least one fix to Drupal itself (session cookie handling stuff, to be precise). As a reward, you'll get a performance bust plus all the goodies of .Net development tools.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) that I've heard good things about :)

Comment: Thanks mikl. I'm going to take a look at this.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth taking a look at [Graffiti](http://graffiticms.com/)

Whilst it's not open source, it is .NET based and has a simple theme engine and plugin architecture. It doesn't have as huge a following as the likes of Drupal, but it's fairly simple to set up and fits your current skillset when it comes to extending it.

**Update**: Graffiti is now open source.

Answer (score 1):

There's [mojoPortal](http://www.mojoportal.com).

It seems it's not as "big" as DotNetNuke (for example), but it has quite a lot of features:

- Blogs, Forums, Event Calendar, Google Maps, Photo Galleries, e-commerce, Secure File Sharing, Newsletter, Surveys, Polls,

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has a community edition of their [SiteFinity](http://www.telerik.com/products/sitefinity.aspx) CMS system.  While I've had great experience with RadControls, I can't vouch for SiteFinity.  It may be worth checking out though, as Telerik has great support for their products.

This maybe an even bigger stretch, but Rob Connery's (the SubSonic guy) [MVC StoreFront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/kona/kona-1/) has good CMS / content publishing capability that has a plugin architeture.  He has published a series of screencasts that revolve around its capability.  Rob gave a preview of the capability at [MIX](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T62F).

Comment: SiteFinity is not open-source!

Comment: @Martin thanks for pointing that out.  @David I'm really looking for something OS, although I have looked at SiteFinity briefly before.  Thanks for all the links and your input, though!

Comment: In regards to the MVC StoreFront, I have watched the majority of those videos and it definitely has some potential.  I'll look into that one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco is excellent. It uses a simular node structure to drupal and very easy to extend thru custom user controls or XSLT. Also i've found that my client who are not the most computer literate people have found the umbraco interface easy to use.